# Entity Framework Upsert but not by Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, upsert

I store animals in an SQL Server database table created by Entity Framework Code First. This is the POCO for it:

```
[Table("Animal")]
public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public byte[] OtherData { get; set; }

    public int ExternalSourceId { get; set; }

    public string ExternalSourceAnimalId { get; set; }
}
```

Some animals are regularly updated by an external source (there are a few sources but a specific animal is updated from maximum 1 source). Also when an external source has a new animal it needs to be inserted. Some animals are maintained locally, these have no external source.

An external source have the Animal identified by the `ExternalSourceAnimalId`. These are unique for one source but there are chances of 2 sources using overlapping IDs, so `ExternalSourceId` is also there to make the 2 of them a combined natural key.

So I get a huge list of animals from an external source and I need to insert or update them in the local database depending on the existence of the specific external key in our datebase.

This is my current solution on doing this (in a class inheriting form [SharpRepository](https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository)):

```
public void InsertOrUpdateAnimal(ExternalAnimal exAnimal, int externalSourceId)
{
    var animal = DbSet.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ExternalSourceId == externalSourceId && o.ExternalSourceAnimalId == exAnimal.Id);

    if (animal != null)
    {
        CopyData(exAnimal, animal); // copies the properties from exAnimal to animal
        this.Update(animal);
    }
    else
    {
        animal = new Animal();
        CopyData(exAnimal, animal);
        this.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

Since this is a bulk operation and takes quite some time I was wondering if there is a faster solution for this. For example if there is a way to upsert in a single database operation.

Comment: Can you do this in a concurrency-safe way? You could first collect the existing IDs and (in an in-memory loop) mark animals as Modified when their IDs match.